# Get lines until first matched pattern range

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I have a file that looks like as follows:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line5
line2
```

I want to get data between `line1` and `line5`. I used `awk '/line1/,/line5/' myfile`. Expecting that output will be:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

But awk reads until last matched `line5`. I desire that awk shall stop on first match and not on last match.

Comment: please add sample input/output..

Comment: Sample data is really going to help here.

Comment: Don't add information in a comment; edit your question to include the requisite information.

Comment: Hope my edits will work

Comment: For me `awk` on the example works correctly: https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fPyczL9VQXwdMm@r//w/mc4FIIzBpDCZNwKQpmDQDk@ZIIkYA

Comment: That should print just the lines between `line1` and `line5`. But note that if you have another `line1`, the block will start again. You'll need to explicitly `exit` or set a flag or something to prevent it

Answer (score 3):

I can’t reproduce your problem. Awk<sup>*</sup> does what I would expect: print each line between the first occurrence of `line1` until the first occurrence of `line5`:

```
$ awk '/line1/,/line5/' file
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

Is it possible that you have a hidden non-printing character somewhere within the string `line5` in the fifth line of your file? This would explain why `awk` isn’t matching it.

---

You can double-check by running the `sed` equivalent:

```
$ sed -n '/line1/,/line5/p' file
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

The `-n` instructs `sed` to not print every line (its default behaviour) while `/line1/,/line5/p` instructs it to print each line from the first match of `line1` until the first match of `line5`.

---

If you want to print only the **first** set of lines starting with a line that matches the pattern `line1` and ending with a line that matches `line5`, you could use:

```
sed -n '/line1/,$p;/line5/q' file
```

---

<sup>*</sup> I checked using `gawk`, the GNU implementation of `awk` (and Kusalananda has confirmed that `awk` and `mawk` on OpenBSD also do the right thing).

Comment: FWIW, OpenBSD `awk` and `mawk` also does the correct thing.

Comment: If there's a non-printing character in the fifth line, it would need to be somewhere _within the string `line5`_ for it not to match.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks for the information about OpenBSD awk and mawk.  I've also incorporated your clarification; that was what I had intended but had not made sufficiently explicit.

Answer (score 2):

You could use below `awk`:

```
awk '/line1/{prnt=1} prnt{print} /line5/{exit}' infile
```

This will print lines matched with `line1` until next first line matched with `line5` then exits immediately.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/foo/,/bar/'
```

prints *all* the sections of the file that start with a line matching `foo` and end with the next line after that (or even the same line contrary to the `sed` equivalent) that matches `bar` (and note that the `line1` regexp also matches on a line that contains `line1anything` including `line10`).

If you wanted to match on the *first* section starting with a line that matches `line1` and ending with the next line after that (or the same line) that matches `line5`, you could do:

```
sed '/line1/,$!d;/line5/q' < file
```

(note that if there's no line that matches `line5` after the first one that matches `line1`, it will print from the `line1` line to the end of the file. Also note that `sed` patterns are *basic* regular expressions, while `awk` ones are extended ones).